# $addToSet with create [Mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to do something like this:

```
Code.create({
            childCode: {"$addtToSet": code.child},
            parentCode: code.parent
        }
```

But this not working, any solution for this?

I need to add unique ObjectId inside the `childCode`...

Comment: addtToSet vs addToSet is that a typo ?

Comment: What is a diffirence?

Comment: extra 't' after add

Comment: When I remove `t` it still same result...

Answer (score 1):

$addToSet can only be used with update() and findAndModify(). what you are trying to do is not possible.

The $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.

The reason why you cannot use it with create is because the document actually doesn't exist in mongoDB and $addToSet is not aware of any array field on which it need to operate.

if your aim is to eliminate duplicates code.child then you probably need to restrict that in your node.js code.